# Given one established tcp connection from client to server, is a second one resolved without server explicitly calling accept?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

Apologies in advance if my terminology is very rudimentary:

I am working with a client that establishes a tcp connection to a server. The client's socket is nonblocking, so after calling `connect()`, the client waits for the socket to become writable.

Upon `accept()`ing the connection from the client, the server performs a blocking operation (call it function X) and does not return to blocking at `accept()` for a long time.

During this time that the server is occupied performing function X, the client does another `connect()` to the same server, again using a nonblocking socket (different than the socket used with the first connection), then waiting for the socket to become writable in order to consider the tcp connection as "established."

I naively expected the second socket to remain not-writable until the server called `accept()` a second time to accept that second connection. But I've observed this as not the case: the second socket becomes writable quickly, so the client again considers this new tcp connection as "established."

**Is this expected?**

From one of the comments at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603485/why-is-nonblocking-socket-writable-before-connect-or-accept), I (very loosely) understand that nonblocking sockets that are in the middle of a tcp connect will remain not-writable for the duration that TCP handshaking is being performed - is this true? Does this relate to the above question? Is it something like: *if there is an existing tcp connection from a client to a server, then subsequent tcp connections from that same client to that same server are immediately/quickly "resolved" (the socket becomes writable without the server explicitly performing a second `accept`*)?

**What I tried**:

I tried writing up a unit test to simulate this scenario with one thread each for client and server running on a single PC, but I *think* this is not a valid way to test: per [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603485/why-is-nonblocking-socket-writable-before-connect-or-accept) I think if client and server are on the same PC, "TCP handshaking" is not quite the same as with two separate PCs, and for example, the client's connecting socket becomes writable without the server even *listening* let alone *accepting* the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `connect()` needs a corresponding `accept()` in order for client and server to communicate with each other.

However, it is possible/likely that the 3-way TCP handshake maybe/is completed while the connection is still in the server's backlog, before `accept()` creates a new socket for it.  Once the handshake is complete, the connection is "established", and that will complete the `connect()` operation on the client's side, even if the connection has not been `accept()`ed yet on the server side.

See [How TCP backlog works in Linux](http://veithen.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html)

Comment: "it is possible/likely that the 3-way TCP handshake maybe/is completed while the connection is still in the server's backlog, before accept() creates a new socket for it" -- this resolution of the TCP handshake seems like it would result in the client's nonblocking socket (in the middle of awaiting connection resolution) becoming writable (so, for example, it would unblock a `select()` that has that socket in its `writefds`) - is that accurate of me to infer?

Comment: @StoneThrow yes, that is correct.  As soon as the 3way handshake completes, the connection is in the "established" state, and the associated socket becomes writable.